# Warning message from npm after installing node v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I installed the latest node.js v13. After the installation, I ran `npm -g upgrade` and got the following warnings;

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v13.0.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v13.0.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

How to clear the warnings? Any side effects if I ignore?

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

npm@6.12.1 has just been released. I have tested that running `install -g npm` on my PC will solve the problem.

Credit goes to the person who posted the comment in this link;
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30066#issuecomment-547551833

Comment: wrong command posted, correct command is npm install -g npm

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs version you have installed v13.0.0 doesn't support npm.
With new npm releases you will able to use node using npm.
You may need to downgrade node if you want to use npm.

There is an already issue reported on github. Please check link :
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30066

Comment: What use is node without npm? This is bad